# Returning list using @Responsebody or return ModelAndView from spring controller which one better

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

First of all my language is not good and sorry for that and i am working with small organization and i am not getting coding standards or suggestions in the office .so let me know to  which process uses in the well defined java projects among return List,Map and model object OR return ModelAndView from Controller in spring.Because for complex tables in the jsp's i think myself its not the better way to return json formatted List and handle them  using jquery instead of that just throw a model and view and use static html components in the jsp's and populate the tables using model object.If you suggest return Collection List i need to add jackson processor jar files and having nearly 1mb size otherwise an jsp just 2kb size. Please help me to follow the correct way in what cases we generally use among one.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Viswam,

The answer depends mostly on your application and the functionality you want to achieve, there is no standard solution here.

If your application is a single page application (read [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) article) or you want RESTful application, I would suggest to stick with `@ResponseBody`, reason is simple, it supports AJAX and basically doesnt change the page from Server side.

You can easily populate any complex table using plain JavaScript or jQuery from the JSON response you receive.

Also if I were to think, I wouldn't want to waste my resources at server side for populating data in JSP and then send it over to client(browser) when it can do this by itself. But this is strictly a ***personal choice/preference.***

And, If you need to redirect to or reload a page, I believe ModelAndView is the way to go.

**Suggestion :** You can check the Spring Code from various tutorials and projects on GitHub or similar platforms/blogs to learn how to keep your code clean and readable.

The best way to learn Best Practices is first code-reading and second actually Practicing them.

Also I dont think a dependency of 1 MB size should be a headache in today's world.

Comment: Thank you **indy**                                                        Now i can relax with your reply and i will start to search projects on suggested place and keep learning to write clean and readable code. And if you don't mind one more question i have and that is some tutorials which i have refered says that using spring **Form** tags is been good over static HTML's with JQUERY AJAX.I am in little bit confusion and still we are using jsp's with HTML components and AJAX requests,so please suggest me that do we need to migrate to spring FORM TAGS or continue with previous.Which is better